# convert regular for to list comprehension

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have this code (below) and I'd like to convert this to a *'list comprehension'* way:

```
order = [1]
for num2 in range(2,10):
    if num2%order[-1]  == 0:
        order.append(num2)
```

this code just generate a list where `ai<ai+1` **and** `ai+1%ai==0` :

> [1, 2, 4, 8]

how Can I use a list comprehension in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a list comprehension for this. The list won't get bound to a name until the comprehension ends, so there's no way for the expression building each value (after the first) to refer to it.

If you need to be able to create the list as an expression, put your current loop in a function that you can call. You might then think about converting it into a generator, rather than returning a list, but that's a separate design choice.

A final point: Your code happens to be producing powers of 2, though that's not how you're calculating them. If that's really all you need, you *can* create the same output with a list comprehension:

```
order = [2**i for i in range(4)]
```

You do have to specify the number of results though (e.g. `4` in my comprehension), instead of an upper bound to the values (e.g. `10` in your original loop).